# How do I get the key of a dictionary using its index?

Tags: typescript, dictionary

Taking the below code as an example, I want to remove the second element in the dictionary assuming that the index of the element is already known.

```
var scores: any = {}
scores.bill = 10
scores.john = 20
scores.smith = 30
```

I tried using `delete scores[1]` but it didn't work. It didn't even give any errors. It just didn't do anything at all. If I change the index to the key name (`delete scores["john"]`), then it deletes but I want to delete using the index and not the key. How do I do that?

I figured I could get the key using a function like `charAt()` or something but it doesn't seem to work with a dictionary. Is there some other function like `charAt()` for a dictionary?

Comment: FYI, in TypeScript and JavaScript, what you've shown is termed an object, not a dictionary. If you want to "delete by index" (which is not guaranteed to be what you think it is), you'd need to get the list of keys, then find the key at the index you think it's at, and delete that.

Comment: Just to make the points mentioned above a bit clearer: Objects (what you consinder being dictionaries) are unordered, so you cannot trust on their element order. However, Arrays (which might consider being lists) can be accessed by indices as Arrays are ordered and hence the element order does not change. However, Arrays do not have keys to access the elements stored in it.

Comment: You *can* (but that doesn't mean you *should*) do `delete theobject[Object.keys(theobject)[1]]` but the outcome of that is not really deterministic as the properties of an object don't have a defined order.

Comment: Although arrays do not have names, @albert :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey: For sure, I missed that part :) Edited my comment accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects do not have an order you can really rely on. They do internally have an order, which follows rules, but it is not quite as simple as the order the properties were added, and you will have differences between different browsers.

It's possible to get an array of the keys, and then find some key in that array by its index. However, there's no guarantee that index 1 will still be "john", so this code is unreliable:

```js
const scores = {};
scores.bill = 10;
scores.john = 20;
scores.smith = 30;

const keys = Object.keys(scores);
 // Happens to log out "john" for this simple case, but you cannot rely on this
console.log(keys[1]);
delete scores[keys[1]]
```

If there's an order that you care about, then you need to write your own code to track that, probably using an array. For example:

```
const scores = {};
const order = ['bill', 'john', 'smith'];
scores.bill = 10;
scores.john = 20;
scores.smith = 30;

delete scores[order[1]];
```